# Kinect Version 2 app development without the sensor

Tags: kinect, kinect-sdk

I have kinect xbox 360, but i have to develop an app to work on Kinect V2 which woks with Kinect SDK 2 that is not compatible with kinect 360, the question here is, Is there a way to test the application targeted for Kinect V2 using Kinect X360 ? or Is there a way to emulate kinect V2 ? or Do i have to get Kinect V2 to develop an app to work on it ?

Comment: Look at it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14382843/kinect-emulation-w-o-actual-device-plugged

Comment: Yes, Kinect Studio emulates the complete Kinect v2 sensor, like it is plugged to the usb port. The *.xef file format is use for playback in that case.

Comment: But do i have to get a Kinect sensor to record data using Kinect Studio in the first place ?